# Create a WCF Client request using ws-security and including a Saml2Assertion in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, saml-2.0, ws-security

I've to call a wcf service using a client certificate and including into the Security header a custom Saml2Assertion that i've pre-built. The SOAP request should looks like:

```
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action>
      ... ACTION ...
    </wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>47dca6bd-e36d-474a-9e92-3febdd0f123f</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:To>....</wsa:To>
    <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <saml2:Assertion ID="_1d3708b9bba9b32904c0164a08d58a93" IssueInstant="2023-09-23T13:29:22.614Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <saml2:Issuer>ISSUER</saml2:Issuer>
        <ds:Signature>
          <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod ... />
            <ds:SignatureMethod ... />
            <ds:Reference URI="#_1d3708b9bba9b32904c0164a08d58a93">
              <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform ... />
                <ds:Transform ...>
                  <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="xsd"
                  xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </ds:Transform>
              </ds:Transforms>
              <ds:DigestMethod ... />
              <ds:DigestValue>....</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
          </ds:SignedInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2023-09-23T13:29:22.614Z">
          <saml2:AuthnContext>
            <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
              urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:X509
            </saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
          </saml2:AuthnContext>
        </saml2:AuthnStatement>
        <saml2:AttributeStatement>
          <!-- Custom Attributes -->
          <saml2:Attribute Name="CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_NAME" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
            <saml2:AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">

              ... CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE VALUE ...

            </saml2:AttributeValue>
          </saml2:Attribute>

        </saml2:AttributeStatement>
      </saml2:Assertion>
    </Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    ... REQUEST ...
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Using the solution found at link [text](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/saml-token-provider) didn't help

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you collected any error logs? You can use [WCF Trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing) to get it.